# Excel countifs on date table column

Tags: excel, countif

I have a excel table, with various columns, 
Date, Name, LE, and so on. In LE column values are either L or E.
Date, Name, LE

- 4/4/2018, Jan, L
- 4/3/2018, Jed, L
- 4/1/2018, Jan, L
- 3/25/2018, Jan, E

Note actual date is like 4/4/2018 but formatted so it display like 4-April-18

Now I want to count how many times L appears for a particular name in a particular month. For example in month of March, ABC has XXX L.

At this time I am adding additional column after date column which display month's number from date column. But I don't like to have additional column and finding ways to directly check month from date column.

My formula is like this:
`=COUNTIFS(tblXYZ[Name],"ABC",  tblXYZ[LE],"L", tblXYZ[Month],"Mar")`
It work fine and give required result.

But when I try 
`=COUNTIFS(tblXYZ[Name],"ABC",  tblXYZ[LE],"L", tblXYZ[Date],"Mar")`

it don't work, 
when I use MONTH() with table column it don't work and generate error
`=COUNTIFS(tblXYZ[Name],"ABC",  tblXYZ[LE],"L", Month(tblXYZ[Date]),3)`

so I have to extract month from Date column directly in the formula but I am unable to find a way.

I am using Excel 2013.

Comment: Showing some actual data would help. Especially seeing how Date is formatted.

Comment: added few line for data in question, date enter as 4/3/2018 and formatted as 3-April-18 (for easy to read).

Answer (score 2):

In general the first parameter of CountIfS() is a range, and pretty much you are trying not to give a range, but an array of months, thus `SUMPRODUCT()` suits you way better:

[COUNIFS support.office.com](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)

---

This is for a single condition:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--MONTH(tblXYZ[Date]=3))
```

This is for two conditions:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--MONTH(tblXYZ[Date]=3)*(tblXYZ[LE]="L"))
```

---

The `--MONTH(tblXYZ[Date]=3)` is a trick, converting boolean data to `0` and `1`. You can see how it works with Ribbon>Formulas>Evaluate Formulas in Excel.

Comment: @user21354 - what do you mean by "odd result"? Wrong?  Have you tried to evaluate the formula through `Ribbon>Formulas>Evaluate Formulas` and to see why is it wrong?

Comment: yes wrong result, same result for every month! if I add *(tblXYZ[Name]="name") then different result but still wrong. try to evaluate but difficult to understand. I think i need to learn more on SUMPRODUCT I did not have idea that it can be use for count.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
=COUNTIFS(tblXYZ[Name],"ABC", tblXYZ[LE],"L", tblXYZ[Month(Date)],"3")
```

Comment: thanks for quick response, but not luck. tblXYZ [ month (date) ] not working. And this is what I am trying to find where to put Month and does it work at all or it is not allowed. as it is generating error

Comment: Got it. MONTH function in Excel will give you the number instead of Text. Try the updated version.

Comment: Yes that give 3 for march,but I think the problem is using function with dynamic range, i.e. month(table[column]) or table[month(column)] both way it is not working